# Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

I am trying to overload the `-` minus operator in a sample C# console application but I am getting an error which I do not understand. I am learning from [this](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Beginning-Visual-C-2012-Programming.productCd-1118314417,descCd-ERRATA.html) book but the errata doesn't list this as typo or error. The overloaded `+` operator works fine but the `-` doesn't.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class AddClass1
    {
        public int val;

        public static AddClass1 operator +(AddClass1 p1, AddClass1 p2)
        {
            AddClass1 returnVal = new AddClass1();
            returnVal.val = p1.val + p2.val;
            return returnVal;
        }

        public static AddClass1 operator -(AddClass1 p1)
        {
            AddClass1 returnVal = new AddClass1();
            returnVal.val = -p1.val;
            return returnVal;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AddClass1 i = new AddClass1();
            i.val = 10;
            AddClass1 j = new AddClass1();
            j.val = 5;
            AddClass1 sum = i + j;
            AddClass1 difference = i - j;

            Console.WriteLine(sum.val);
            Console.WriteLine(difference.val);
        }
    }
}
```

Error

```
Error   1   Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'ConsoleApplication1.AddClass1' and 'ConsoleApplication1.AddClass1'  c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs 37  36  ConsoleApplication1
```

On this line

```
AddClass1 difference = i - j;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to overload binary `-` operator.

```
public static AddClass1 operator -(AddClass1 p1, AddClass1 p2)
{
    AddClass1 returnVal = new AddClass1();
    returnVal.val = p1.val - p2.val;
    return returnVal;
}
```

So you can use it like `c = a + b`

---

What you've done is unary `-`

```
public static AddClass1 operator -(AddClass1 p1)
{
    AddClass1 returnVal = new AddClass1();
    returnVal.val = -p1.val;
    return returnVal;
}
```

Which can be used in this way

```
AddClass1 j = new AddClass1();
j.val = 5;
AddClass1 negative = -j;//this is what you have done
```

Answer (score 3):

You didn't overload your `-` operator correctly. You need a `binary operator`,

```
public static AddClass1 operator -(AddClass1 p1, AddClass1 p2)
{
    AddClass1 returnVal = new AddClass1();
    returnVal.val = p1.val - p2.val;
    return returnVal;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have overloaded a unary minus; you should overload the binary one.

```
public static AddClass1 operator -(AddClass1 p1, AddClass1 p2)
{
    return new AddClass1 { val = p1.val-p2.val };
}
```

Comment: Thank you that makes perfect sense. I have not realized that, dumb mistake!

Answer (score 2):

You overloaded the **unary** negation operator, not the **binary** subraction operator.  Because of the overload that you have you can write:

```
AddClass1 negation = -i;
```

Or even:

```
AddClass1 difference = i + (-j);
```

To write:

```
AddClass1 difference = i - j;
```

You need to overload the

```
public static AddClass1 operator -(AddClass1 p1, AddClass1, p2)
```

operator.

Answer (score 1):

Your class has only unary minus overloaded. So, this will work:

```
AddClass1 difference = i + (-j);
```

To allow your expression(`i - j`) just overload binary minus (like binary plus overloaded)

Answer (score 1):

You did not define this as a binary (accepting two values) operator.  What you have defined is negation.  Try this:

```
    public static AddClass1 operator -(AddClass1 p1, AddClass1 p2)
    {
        AddClass1 returnVal = new AddClass1();
        returnVal.val = p1.val - p2.val;
        return returnVal;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class AddClass1
    {
        public int val;

        public static AddClass1 operator +(AddClass1 p1, AddClass1 p2)
        {
            AddClass1 returnVal = new AddClass1();
            returnVal.val = p1.val + p2.val;
            return returnVal;
        }

        public static AddClass1 operator -(AddClass1 p1, AddClass1 p2)
        {
            AddClass1 returnVal = new AddClass1();
            returnVal.val = p1.val - p2.val;
            return returnVal;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AddClass1 i = new AddClass1();
            i.val = 10;
            AddClass1 j = new AddClass1();
            j.val = 5;
            AddClass1 sum = i + j;
            AddClass1 difference = i - j;

            Console.WriteLine(sum.val);
            Console.WriteLine(difference.val);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```